# is a line segment a polygon, I guess the answer is `yes`, I just need a double confirmation.

Tags: polygons

per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon), a polygon is

> a plane figure that is described by a finite number of straight line
>   segments connected to form a closed polygonal chain or polygonal
>   circuit.

"is a line segment a polygon"? i searched this question on math.stackexchange, and didn't get a related post though, this [post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/34225/128889) on gamedev.stackexchange is discussing this question.

I guess the answer is `yes`, I just need  a double confirmation.

a well-recognized textbook claim this would be appreciated.

Comment: Nope. A polygon is a plane figure that consists of finite number of  line segments which connected to form a **closed polygonal chain**. A single line segment itself doesn't form a closed polygonal chain. If you have two line segments, one from $A$ to $B$ and another one from $B$ to $A$, you can argue these "two" segment together forms a degenerate polygon.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by polygon. There are several possible definitions, some of which say yes, some of which say no. I assume you don't yet have a definition in mind, so what things should be polygons to you? Is a polygon a sequence of line segments, or the region bounded by a sequence of line segments? Is a polygon allowed to intersect itself? Should the interior be nonempty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the definition on wiki, a more authoritative reference is
Hilbert's [The foundations of geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1537072986). In $\S 4$, a polygon is defined as follows

> A system of segments $AB, BC, CD, \ldots, KL$ is called a broken line joining $A$ with $L$ ...... The points lying within the segments $AB, BC, CD, \ldots, KL$, as also the points $A,B,C,D,\ldots,K,L$, are called *the points of the broken line*. In particular, if the point $A$ coincides with $L$, the broken line is called a polygon...

The key part is the starting point $A$ coincides with the ending point $L$.
This is the same as the requirement of **closed polygon chain** on wiki.

By this definition, a single line segment cannot be a chain (unless it reduces to a single point).

A polygon isn't just a collection of its points. In addition to its points, it also contain the geometrical/combinatorial information like where are the vertices and how are the vertices connected.